# Multiple different data types in one file

Tags: r

I am reading in a large data file, with 2000 rows and 3000 columns. To my knowledge, the file only contains integers. However, when I use `fread` in R, I get the following unique classes across columns:

"logical"   "integer"   "integer64" "numeric"

I expected there to be "logical", because sometimes the data contains NA. But why does a single file contain multiple different classes across columns? Is it normal that some columns are integer, others are integer64 and others are numeric?

Comment: It is automatically picking up the type based on the column values.  `logical` can be because if there is only NA and by default it is NA_logical_.  Also, check the `.Machine$integer.max` if it is above that it can be parsed differently

Comment: @akrun alright that makes sense. So this mix is not an issue I assume.

Comment: WIth `fread`, it is also loaded with `int64`.  So that may be the reason some columns with large values are converted to integer64.  But, you can always override with `colClasses` argument where you specify the required type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to `?fread`

> All controls such as sep, colClasses and nrows are automatically detected.

> bit64::integer64, IDate, and POSIXct types are also detected and read directly without needing to read as character before converting.

The `logical` type can occur if the column have only `NA` elements and by default it is the `NA_logical_` which is `logical` and as we are not specifying the `colClasses`, it automatically checks and converts to different type.  If we want to override, specify the `colClasses` as a vector of values for each column in that order of occurence

Comment: thanks that helps. But one more thing: I read that numeric also captures decimal values in R (besides integers). I would be interested in finding if there is any decimal value in my data table. How can this be done?

Comment: @EtoAls Do you want to find a numeric column from an integer column?

Comment: No, I just want to find out why my datatable has numeric columns at all. I think it should have only integer and integer64. I am worried that some numbers are decimal values (which they should not be)

Comment: @EtoAls it could be based on the data from the csv.  Can you check the original data column to see its format

Comment: yes, the format is just "Default" when I open the file with Excel and check a cell. From what I see, the columns just contain integers, and sometimes NAs.

Comment: @EtoAls Do you have any NAs in the columns that read as integers

Comment: yes they have also NAs. I also realized some of the very large numbers are in scientifc notation displayed in Excel, if that plays a role.

Comment: @EtoAls I think you could manually create a new dataset with only few only few rows from the data you have without any NA and check if you can reproduce the same type for each column

Comment: @EtoAls Or you can specify the `colClasses` argument in `fread` and force it to read in a specific type.

Comment: that's hard to do, I would have to delete a lot of NAs manually. But what I just did is calculate the sum of one row which is displayed as "numeric" in R, by ignoring NAs. The result is an integer. So I am not worried anymore that these columns contain decimal values :)

Comment: @EtoAls It is not clear why you are concerned about the `integer` or `numeric` type.  You could always change it with `colClasses` or after reading the data with `as.integer` or `as.numeric` etc

Comment: very true. I was just trying to understand how fread determines column types. My file has only integers and NAs, so I do not understand the mix of column types (numeric - integer). integer64 makes sense though, as some numbers become quite large.

Comment: @EtoAls Once it reaches the integer max value, it is read either as numeric or as integer64.  Choosing either one of them have to do with how it parses the values